# SFSafariViewController Done Button Tappable Area Too Small

Tags: ios, button, swiftui, sfsafariviewcontroller

There is another post on SO regarding this issue but it's from a while back and only deals with UIKit, not SwiftUI. I have SFSafariViewController working perfectly, and am using it via a programmatic NavigationLink.

The issue is that the tappable area of the Done button is too small. I can only tap on the "ne" of the word "Done" and only at a certain angle. It's very strange and I haven't been able to solve the issue. The rest of the buttons all work perfectly.

If I change to using it modally via a sheet, the Done button works perfectly, but I need to use it via a NavigationLink.

I just need to solve the problem with the tappable area of the Done button.

Thanks!

Here's my SFSafariViewController:

```
import SwiftUI
import SafariServices

struct SafariView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss

    let url: URL

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> SFSafariViewController {
        let vc = SFSafariViewController(url: url)
        vc.preferredControlTintColor = .tintColor
        vc.delegate = context.coordinator
        return vc
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ vc: SFSafariViewController, context: Context) {}

    class Coordinator: NSObject, SFSafariViewControllerDelegate {
        var dismissAction: DismissAction?

        func safariViewControllerDidFinish(_ controller: SFSafariViewController) {
            dismissAction?()
        }
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        let coordinator = Coordinator()
        coordinator.dismissAction = dismiss
        return coordinator
    }
}
```

Here's my view:

```
import SwiftUI

struct HomeView: View {

    @State private var isBtnActive: Bool = false

    var body: some View {

        NavigationLink(
            destination: SafariView(url: URL(string: "https://www.example.com")!)
                .navigationBarHidden(true),
            isActive: $isBtnActive,
            label: {
                EmptyView()
            }
        )
        .accessibilityHidden(true)

        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            Spacer()
            Button("Show Website") {
                isBtnActive = true
            }
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```